# Driving an electromagnet with a 556 timer

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm trying to drive an electromagnet with a 556 timer in a push pull configuration. The magnet has to change polarity rather quickly and sharply about 10 to 20khz. The voltage also has to be variable, between 3 to 15 volts the current draw is in the range of 1amp. What I need is a way to amp the square waves, I was thinking of using a pair of relays driven by the 556 timer in the complimentary configuration that way I can feed through them a varying voltage independently without affecting the 556... Or am I going at this the wrong way?

Comment: Relays won't get you anywhere close to 20kHz.

Comment: What are you doing with the magnet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to build or buy something called an H-bridge. They are commonly used for motor control.

Comment: Try the National LMD18200D, or a kit that lets you connect to one.

Comment: @pingswept: that's a nice part, roughly like the L298N, but diodes included.

Comment: I tried a H-bridge made by Cana Kit and it works like a charm! I'm still using the 556 timer in complimentary configuration mode and it works perfectly. Thank you very much for the advice Joeforker!